# Accessing Mobile camera and microphone

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I am going to develop a general application for mobile which will be used for video chatting.Therefore I need to access mobile camera and mic. Is there any functionality in javascript or jQuery by which I will be able to do that.
Note: as it is a general function, so it should be able to access the camera of any mobile device.

Comment: Currently Opera Mobile 12 only support getUserMedia (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572859/will-and-when-will-mobile-browers-support-getusermedia/11575783#11575783) --- so you can use opera-prefixed version of getUserMedia to access mic/cams --- other mobile clients have no support yet!

Answer (score 3):

You can use PhoneGap functionality which uses JavaScript, it's platform independent. You can use the method `navigator.device.capture.captureVideo` of [PhoneGap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_media_capture_capture.md.html#capture.captureVideo).

Answer (score 0):

There is [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/reference/getting-started).

But today, even if it aims at being the standard, [it doesn't work on all browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC).

I don't think you'll find a standard (non flash or plugin based) and ready library enabling you to use the camera.

Comment: Is there any other way to do it? Or I have to do native coding for different OS?

Comment: I guess you'll have to do native coding. But there aren't so many big platforms today.

Comment: @RichBradshaw You're right I was much too restrictive. Updated. Last time I had a look I thought it was too soon but maybe we'll be able to use it in near future...

Answer (score 0):

For a solution that actually just "works" and allows you to utilize the device's hardware properly, you'll need to code for native apps specific to the platform you're targeting. (ex. -> iOS, Android, etc.)