# Will and When will Mobile Browers support getUserMedia?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, mobile, html5-video, webrtc

I have written a web app using the 'bleeding edge' HTML5/WebRTC API's (See code below). This works on Chrome v20 (with MediaStream flag enabled) and latest FF Nightly build 17.0a1 (with “media.navigator.enabled” pref created and set to true). I havent yet got it working on Opera.

However, my question is, will this work on future mobile versions of these browers? and If so when?

```
if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia){   
   //For WebKit (Chrome/ Safari)
   navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({video: true, audio: false}, function(localMediaStream)      {
          $("#video").attr("src",window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream)); 
    }, function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    });
}else if(navigator.mozGetUserMedia){
  //For Firefox
  navigator.mozGetUserMedia({video: true}, function(localMediaStream) {
  var video = document.querySelector('video');  
  video.src = localMediaStream;
  video.play();
    },  function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    });
}else if(navigator.getUserMedia){
    //For Opera
    navigator.getUserMedia({audio: false, video: true}, function(localMediaStream) {
    $("#video").attr("src", localMediaStream);                                  
    },  function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently [Opera Mobile 12.0 only support getUserMedia API](http://caniuse.com/stream) - however I'm expecting that other mobile clients 'll start supporting it at the beginning of the 2013.

**Updated at 3:57 am - Wednesday, 21 May 2014 (UTC)**

Now, **all major three browsers** are **supporting WebRTC** (*getUserMedia + PeerConnection + RTCDataChannel*) on android:

1. [Firefox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox) - *its a Google App Store link*
2. [Chrome](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrome.beta&hl=en) - *its a Google App Store link*
3. [Opera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opera.browser) - *its a Google App Store link*

You can use [cross-walk project](https://crosswalk-project.org/) and compile your HTML into cross-platform apk files and it will work! It supports All WebRTC features i.e. *getUserMedia + PeerConnection + RTCDataChannel*.

Comment: Chrome Android Beta (26) and above support the WebRTC APIs including getUserMedia. In Beta 26 you'll need to enable WebRTC support from about:flags.

Comment: And Firefox Mobile support was added in version 24.